# Google cloud messaging unreliable between devices? Switch to other protocol or other service?

Tags: php, android, cloud, messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am working for a few days on an app which is based on real time communication between devices. In the past I was using GCM for notifications via POST methods using the OkHttp library. So far, so good.

But when it comes to real time communication I face a lot of issues around connection timeouts or even mesages which are never delivered.

My implementation is simple. First the user from his phone sends a request via POST and my online server to another phone (driver) which than confirms the request and replies back to the sender via another POST method and via the online server.

But only about 80% of the replies get back to the user, or they arrive after several minutes.

Can the problem be in my implementation?? Or should I switch to GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP)??

I am in serious need of some suggestions, please light me up.
Regards.

Php implementation:

```
<?php

include_once '../includes/db_connect.php'; 

// Query database for driver's regId
 if(!empty($_POST["str"])) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM DRIVERS WHERE NAME = '$_POST[driver]' " ;
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

    $gcmRegID  = $row["REGID"]; 
    $clientId = $_POST["clientId"]; 
    $street = $_POST["str"]; 
    $number = $_POST["nr"]; 
    $bloc = $_POST["bl"]; 
    $scara = $_POST["sc"]; 
    if (isset($gcmRegID)) {    
      $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
      $message = array("jstr" => $street, "jnr" => $number, "jbl" => $bloc, "jsc" => $scara, "jId" => $clientId); 
      $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
    }   
 }

  // Reply to the client if available or not
  if(!empty($_POST["response"])) { 
     $gcmRegID  = $_POST["clientId"]; 
     $response = $_POST["response"];      
      $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
      $message = array("jresp" => $response); 
      $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);

 }

  //generic php function to send GCM push notification
   function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message

        );
    // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "**************");    
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);       
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Order Activity - for sending request to the driver

```
public void callDriver (View view){
    MySendTask send = new MySendTask();
    send.execute();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Pressed :)", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private class MySendTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String str = streetName.getText().toString();
String nr = streetNr.getText().toString();
String bl = bloc.getText().toString();
String sc = scara.getText().toString();     

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Notification", MODE_PRIVATE);
String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");   


    try {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("clientId", registrationId)
            .add("driver", "Peter Bleul")
            .add("str", str)
            .add("nr", nr)
            .add("bl", bl)
            .add("sc", sc)

            .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://edmon.net/andr/index.php")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            System.out.println(response.body().string());               


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
                return null;
            }               

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Order successfully sent!", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an excellent example, with great sample applications explaining the process wonderfully, thanks to: [Antoine Cambell](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial)

I reccomend it for everyone seaking answers for a simmilar application.

Answer (score 0):

GCM does not guarantee message delivery.  GCM also throttles message delivery which can often result in significant delays.  For more details on this topic see: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html (goto the "Lifetime of a Message" section").

I have experienced issues similar to yours in the app I work on.

Thus it does not seem that GCM is a good candidate for real-time communication.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion in what direction I could look forward? Thanks @EJK

Comment: Sorry I do not.  Some quick Googling shows that GCM still appears to be the service of choice for chat applications.  I could find no discussion of an alternative.  Do read the link to the GCM docs that I posted.  Perhaps you can tune the service behavior to suit your needs.  Some of the message delivery properties look to be configurable.  If this takes you to a solution, then certainly post the answer here.

Comment: I have found an excellent example, with sample applications thanks to [Antoine Cambell](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial) - check it out @EJK